# How to export schema of a database in AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I used the following command from shell to export the schema of the database:

```
mysqldump -u username -p -no-data database_name> gs://test.sql
```

I got the following error:

`mysqldump: unknown option '-o'`.

Then instead I used this:

`mysqldump -u username -p -d database_name`, ( -d instead of -no-data flag)

I got this error:

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

When trying to connect.
Any idea how to export only table definitions in the schema and not all the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the hostname.

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u username -p -d database_name
```

Comment: How do you find the hostname through cloud shell?

Comment: If you select the instance, it's the Primary IP address